# Font Awesome 5, how to style svg pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome, pseudo-element, font-awesome-5

I'm using font awesome 5 pseudo elements to attach an `:after` tag to my element like this

```
&:after {
    content: "\f068";
    font-weight:400;
    color:$brandRed;
    float:right;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"; 
}
```

Which is adding the content in fine, but the styling that I add, specifically `float:right` is not added to the SVG that is generated with font awesome?

[image: Dom Screenshot]

As shown in the image above, the SVG element is loaded correctly, but the `:after` tag has the `float:right` styling on it, and the SVG does not have any of the styling specified? Why is it not taking over the styling?

According to their [docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements), they say to add it like this, with all of your stylings

```
.login::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f007";
}
```

Why are the stylings not carrying over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the pseudo-element technique with the JS version, Font Awesome will use only the properties related to the icon to generate the SVG (content,font-family, font-weight, etc) and the pseudo-element will become useless. If you check the the documentation you will find that you need to add `display:none` to the pseudo element:

> Set Pseudo Elements’ display to none
>
> Since our JS will find each icon reference **(using your pseudo element styling)** and insert an icon into your page’s DOM automatically, we’ll **need to hide the real CSS-created pseudo element that’s rendered**.<sup>[ref](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#with-svg-js)</sup>

If you need to apply properties like `float` you need to apply them to the generated SVG not the pseudo element. So simply target the SVG:

```css
span:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f007";
  /*display:none; I commented this mandatory property to see what is happening */ 
  color:red; /* will do nothing*/
  float:right; /* will do nothing*/
}


/*target the svg for styling*/
.target-svg svg {
  color: blue;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script data-search-pseudo-elements src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<span class="target-svg">the icons is on the right --></span>
<br>
<span>the icons will not be styled</span>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'm assuming the `font-size:0` is required, as without it I have both the icon and a square box?

Comment: @S_R yes the font-size:0 or any other trick is to hide the pseudo element and avoid having 2 icons ... I did find nothing about this in their doc so I actually I don't know if it's a bug or not,

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem like its the expected behaviour. Thanks for your help!